# What's the correct thing to do when someone adds a bogus citation to an answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, anonymous-user

I got a notification about an edit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066729/creating-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch/4066787#4066787). The edit adds a page on "crunchify.com" as the source. The edit has already been approved, with the comment "Added citing because the text for everything before the diagram is taken literally word for word from Crunchify".

But here's the thing: I wrote that answer from scratch. The rare times when I have copied text verbatim in answers I always cite my sources (and I generally blockquote, too).

I've never even heard of "Crunchify" before today. From the history you can see my answer was posted in Nov of 2010. [Whois says crunchify.com was created 06-apr-2013](http://www.whois.com/whois/crunchify.com) and [the Wayback Machine corroborates this](http://web.archive.org/web/20130715000000*/http://crunchify.com/how-to-implement-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch-in-java/). So unless I have incredible precognitive abilities (hint: I don't) I obviously didn't copy from Crunchify. Instead, it looks like they copied from my answer without attribution.

I can edit out the bogus citation, but given that it was added by "Community" I'm worried that it'll just get re-added. What is the correct way to remove this edit and ensure that it never comes back?

Also, was this edit performed by a bot, or does "Community" just take ownership of anonymous edits?

Comment: Answer to the last part is yes, Community takes ownership of anonymous edits. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/204175

Comment: @FDinoff  Having anonymous edits appear to be from a user with the "mod diamond" is unfortunate, as it gives the edit an unwarranted air of authority.

Comment: Actually it doesn't show "Community ♦" for the reviewers, but "anonymous user". Through at the end, those edits are attributed to the -1. I edited your title to reflect this.

Comment: Looks like community does own anon edits see its profile: (http://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) `I do things like:... Own suggested edits from anonymous users`

Comment: I would also contact crunchify. Creative Commons requires they give you credit, and if they don't they are violating your copyright (and I bet SO would back you up, since it's on there site.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

#### General answer

You aren't pleased with the edit?

1. Roll it back.
2. Ping the user that made the edit and explain why you rolled it back (optional).

#### This case

Depending exactly what was modified, you may want to flag for moderator attention, if the edit hijacked spam claiming that is a "reference" or "source". This is so moderators can suspend the reviewers that approved the edit, asking them to be more careful.

Other than that, if they are actually copying Stack Exchange content without proper attribution you may want to [report them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/213575) to the staff and let them deal with it.

---

The site includes a rather lacking reference linking to your answer:

> Ref. You may be interested in list of all Java Tutorials.

animuson rolled the edit back, so I suppose this was solved.

Comment: No need to contact us in this specific case. I've already sent off an email to them about copying our content / attribution requirements.

Comment: FWIW, I'm pretty sure that "Ref" link was just added. The [most recent wayback machine archive of the page](http://web.archive.org/web/20150402220109/http://crunchify.com/how-to-implement-a-linkedlist-class-from-scratch-in-java/) has the "You may be interested in list of all Java Tutorials" sentence without the "Ref" link.

Comment: How do you "ping" a user who edited?

Comment: @animuson I run into copycat sites all the time. You want them reported? How?

Comment: @matt anyone that has its name in the revision history can be pinged in the same way you ping someone in comments.

Comment: @matt [Updated procedure for reporting SCRAPERs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178) the same applies for sites without proper attribution.

Comment: So I should use a comment? Then why is there no autofill for their name after at sign?

Comment: @matt such [feature was declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106534/213575) but yes, even if they are not in the autocomplete, they will be notified.

Comment: Thanks on both. Learned useful stuff today!