# Automated actions and actions from anonymous users should not look the same

Tags: feature-request, community-user, anonymous-user

Edits by anonymous users, if approved, are attributed to the user "Community♦".

At a high level, this user has two very different purposes:

- performing a number of automated tasks, like deleting abandoned questions
- taking ownership of anonymous edits

This is confusing. It is reasonable to expect automated edits to be hard to revoke, as they would just happen again unless the conditions that triggered them in the first place were eliminated, and because automated actions and anonymous actions are attributed to the same user it is hard to distinguish between them.

To make matters worse, the "mod diamond" (♦) on everything Community♦ does gives it an air of greater authority than normal users, while anonymous edits should really be treated as having *less* authority than those from registered users.

I was personally confused by this when I posted [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294227/whats-the-correct-thing-to-do-when-someone-adds-a-bogus-citation-to-an-answer) about a bogus anonymous edit. I originally posted it with the title "What's the correct thing to do when 'Community' adds a bogus citation to an answer", because looking at the answer (with the bogus citation) showed the most recent edit as being from "Community♦". It was unclear to me whether or not this was an automated edit, and so I was not sure if rolling it back would be futile.

Actions (eg: edits) from anonymous users should not appear to be from "Community♦", but instead state that they are from "*anonymous user*", or anything else that would make it obvious that they were not performed by either a robot or a moderator.

While being reviewed, anonymous edits are already shown to reviewers as being from anonymous (not "Community♦") -- this anonymous attribution should persist even after they are approved.

Comment: Note that you can check the edit approval votes (by clicking the "edit approved" link in the revision history) to see if the edit required votes from other users. If the edit was automated, Community will give itself a binding approval vote (I think), while anonymous edits require approval from real users ([as happened in this case](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8051270)). That said, I agree that that's not obvious, and it requires at least two more clicks and page-loads, even if you know where to look for it.

Comment: Any examples of "automated edits"? Aside from the marked MSO/MSE-split-fixups?

Comment: @Deduplicator I think the java.sun.com->java.oracle.com link changes were automated.

Comment: Wait -- I didn't vote for Community. Who did? Take that diamond away!